# How to punctuate two quotes within a sentence

Tags: punctuation, quotations, periods

Should I put a period at the end of the first quote within this sentence?

> We often hear, "That's not me." or "I wasn't raised that way."

OR should it read:

> "That's not me" or "I wasn't raised that way."

Comment: I'm sure there must be an older question that can close this question, I tried looking briefly but gave up because I find punctuation/quotation questions really, really dull.

Comment: Related: [How to Punctuate Two Quoted Independent Clauses Within a Declarative Sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264637/how-to-punctuate-two-quoted-independent-clauses-within-a-declarative-sentence?rq=1) the answer doesn't really answer this question though.

Comment: Here's a related question: [Punctuation within quotes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5951/punctuation-within-quotes).

Answer (score 2):

If you put a period before conjunctions, it is no longer a compound sentence. The sentence ends with a period.

You need to put a comma instead of a period.

We often hear, "That's not me," or "I wasn't raised that way."

Hope it helps.